# How to pick the 2 highest prices paid

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the input data.

```
  Dept            Company                   Code      Payment Amt

Gardeners     Sort:Insurance Carrier        100         20.00
Gardeners     Sort:Insurance Carrier        100         22.00
Gardeners     Sort:Insurance Carrier        100         21.00
Gardeners     Sort:Insurance Carrier        100         20.00
Gardeners     Sort:Insurance Carrier        100         22.00
```

I want to return

```
Sort:Insurance Carrier 100   -  22.00 and 21.00
```

Not 22.00 and 22.00 I fear this code is returning 22 and 22 arguably the 2 top prices paid but not really so.

I have this SQL

```
SELECT 
[DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code] as Code, [Sort: Insurance Carrier], 
SUM(CASE WHEN num = 1 THEN [Pmt Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS [first high], 
SUM(CASE WHEN num = 2 THEN [Pmt Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS [second high] 
FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
[DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
ORDER BY [Pmt Amount] DESC) AS num, 
[DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier], 
[Pmt Amount]
FROM 
[revenuedetail$]
) AS t 
WHERE num IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY [DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same value to have the same number, then you should use  `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`. But you are on the right track!

Also change `sum()` to `max()` to avoid summing the values with the same `dense_rank()`.

Try this:

```
select 
    [dept]
  , [Sort: Procedure Code] as Code
  , [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
  , max(case when num = 1 then [Pmt Amount] else 0 end) as [first high]
  , max(case when num = 2 then [Pmt Amount] else 0 end) as [second high] 
from (
  select 
      dense_rank() over(
        partition by [dept], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
        order by [Pmt Amount] desc
        ) as num
    , [dept]
    , [Sort: Procedure Code]
    , [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
    , [Pmt Amount]
  from [revenuedetail$]
  ) as t 
where num in (1, 2)
group by [dept], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PJCDDC90476

returns:

```
+-----------+------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
|   dept    | Code | Sort: Insurance Carrier | first high | second high |
+-----------+------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
| Gardeners |  100 | Sort:Insurance Carrier  | 22.00      | 21.00       |
+-----------+------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want `dense_rank()` rather than `row_number()`:

```
SELECT [DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code] as Code, [Sort: Insurance Carrier],
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 1 THEN [Pmt Amount] END) AS [first high], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 2 THEN [Pmt Amount] END) AS [second high] 
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier]
                                ORDER BY [Pmt Amount] DESC
                               ) AS num, 
             rd.*
      FROM [revenuedetail$] rd
     ) rd
WHERE num IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY [DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier];
```

Notes:

- I removed the `ELSE 0`.  If there is no second value, then this version returns `NULL` rather than `0`.  I find that more intuitive (add the `ELSE 0` back if that is not the behavior you want).
- I added more meaningful table aliases.  `rd` makes more sense than `t`.
- I used `rd.*` in the subquery.  That actually shortens the query and makes it easier to modify.
- You should reconsider your column names.  All the square braces just make the code harder to write and to read.

Comment: Here we might have to use SELECT distinct DENSE_RANK() .....Since amount 22 is twice in the table, the rank 1 will appear two times and therefore the sum for First high will be 44 and not 22.

Answer (score 0):

If the sql server version is 2012 and above, Then Lead() can be used:

```
select Top 1 [DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], [Sort: Insurance Carrier],
[Pmt Amount] AS [first high],  
Lead([Pmt Amount],1)over(partition by [DEPT], [Sort: Procedure Code], 
[Sort: Insurance Carrier] ORDER BY [Pmt Amount] DESC)AS [Second high]
from [revenuedetail$] order by [Pmt Amount] desc
```